# cambiar de imagen mediante flag

Tags: angularjs

Tengo 2 variables  que manipulen la misma imagen

En el html:

```
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.deleteMessage()" ng-show="!vm.instance.deleted" ng-show="!vm.flagDelete"></i>
```

pero nunca cambia, cual es mi error?

Comment: No veo error pero te recomiendo probar con ng-if

Comment: Hola, podrías agregar el código completo de tu controlador? O por lo menos la función? Saludos

Comment: @KN_ edite mi pregunta

Comment: Otra consulta, el vm.instance.delete se corresponde con el ng-controller="Controller as vm" en el html? en caso de que estés usando en el Controller, en el .js, var vm = this; y después quieras usar el vm en el html, eso puede ser el error.

Comment: @KN_ solo hace caso a una variable, ng-show="!vm.instance.deleted" ng-show="!vm.flagDelete"

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del controlador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paso un ejemplo por si te sirve en plunkr de como hacer que muestre o no:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AtbVEEm1f7IWlpcFLWha?p=preview

Controlador: como puede ver, aquí uso controller as:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.mostrar = true;
  vm.cambiarEstado = function(){
    vm.mostrar = !vm.mostrar;
  }
});
```

Html: aquí también utilizo controllerAs:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <p ng-show='mainCtrl.mostrar'>Parrafo uno</p>
    <p ng-show='!mainCtrl.mostrar'>Parrafo dos</p>
    <button ng-click="mainCtrl.cambiarEstado()">A traves de funcion</button>
    <button ng-click="mainCtrl.mostrar = !mainCtrl.mostrar">Desde el htmln</button>
</body>
```

Adicional a esto, agregué dos formas de cambiar el valor de la variable que controla la visibilidad.

Otra cosa que noto en tu código es que tienes doble ng-show, solo debes tener uno, y en caso de responder a dos variables deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
ng-show="var1 && var2"
```

o

```
ng-show="var || var2"
```

o

```
ng-show="fncRetornaValor()"
```

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, cualquier cosa vuelve a preguntar.

Comment: no sabia que se podia hacer esto  ng-show="var1 && var2", wao que interesante

Comment: es muy flexible en cuanto a operación, cuando la lógica es mas complicada puedes hacer cosas muy interesantes. Dejé actualizado el ejemplo de plunker para que lo veas funcionando también. Saludos